# Is it insecure to trust user input for src attribute of img and video

Tags: html, angularjs, security, xss, src

AngularJS prevents urls from other domains to be set as `src` of `img` and `video` tags, unless one explicitly trust them as resource url via `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl`.

I'm wondering what kind of security issue exists in setting `src` to arbitrary user inputted value? Is it only risk of running js which only applies to old browsers?

Comment: Trusting user input is never a good idea under any circumstances.

Comment: No it is not just about older browsers. Read up on *"XSS" - Cross Site Scripting*